# Question text Mining using Random Forest and PCA

Tags: pca, random-forest, text-mining

I'm currently using the Reuters 50-50 dataset (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Reuter_50_50) to predict authorship. I've tried to first use PCA on both the test and training dataset to get a loading summary of all 50 documents by Author then ran a random tree document. I've also removed the words from the test dataset that are different than the test dataset. I know this hurts my performance a bit, but I don't think it would hurt my performance so much. My accuracy is less than 2%. Is my procedure incorrect? I feel like I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Could someone assist me please?

Comment: can you provide a bit more information about what you have done. Don't include all the code, just the relevant bits to show how you have performed the pca and random forest fit

Comment: From doing more reading, I believe the problem is derived from doing a PCA on the test and training datasets separately rather than doing it at the same time. The problem is that the scaling between PCAs of the test and training dataset would be different resulting in different results. Thus, the predictions would be flawed since the scales could be slightly different. I realized that my approach was incorrect. As a result, I used the TF IDF of all the documents for each author and then did a decision tree on these results. My out of sample accuracy is 99% which is an extremely good result.